# Recreating this particular box

Tags: fonts, formatting

I'm interested in recreating this particular box. **I'd like to do it on my own** however I don't know what kind of tools ( packages , etc. ) are necessary for recreating it.

The box isn't that difficult. My concern is the blue letters. Probably a fancy font?

[image]

Comment: You could most easily do it with the the `tcolorbox` package, along with `xcolor` for colours and `fontspec` with `xelatex` or `lualatex` for the fonts.

Comment: I'm not a XeTeX or LuaTeX user. I'm using pdflatex for all my projects. Yeah , `tcolorbox` is on my mind for the box. Now, for the fonts I'm not quite sure.

Comment: If you don't want to use `xelatex` or `lualatex` (why?) then you are best just to put up without the fancy W and M.

Comment: Probably that way! The reason I'm not using those systems is that most of my partners cannot support it and they do not know how to use it as well. So, using them is out of the option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example I used tcolorbox and xstring.
Here is some useful fonts:
[Font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html).

```
\documentclass[x11names]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{pbsi}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\newcommand{\exampleBox}[2]{
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    colframe=Blue2,
    colback=white,
    top=2pt,
    bottom=2pt,
    left=2pt,
    right=2pt,
    boxrule=1pt
    ]
    \StrSplit{#1}{1}{\firstLetter}{\otherLetters}
    \textcolor{RoyalBlue4}{
      \bsifamily\Huge\MakeUppercase\firstLetter}%
    \textcolor{black}{
      \hspace{-2.2ex}
      \fontfamily{phv}\bfseries\Large
      \scshape\underline{ \textcolor{RoyalBlue1}{\otherLetters}}}

    \vspace{2ex}

    #2

  \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\exampleBox{writing about mathematics}{
  \textcolor{Blue2}{\textbf{Extending the example}}
  bla bla bla...
}
\end{document}
```

This is my result:
[image]

Hope that it could help.

Comment: A, the `pbsi` font... I love that font!